# User Editable Title in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to make the title of a Highcharts chart user-editable. The user should be able to click on the title and change it, and that new title should persist and be exported with the chart. I found a lot of discussion on programatically changing the title, but nothing on letting the user change it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using the chart options. I wrote some code using **`JQuery`** for adding an input which shows and hides on click of the title:

```
$(document).bind("enterKey", function (e) {

    $('.highcharts-title tspan').html($('#inputTitle').val());
    Highcharts.charts[0].options.title.text = $('#inputTitle').val();
    $('#inputTitle').css("visibility", "hidden");
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});

$('.highcharts-title').on("click", function () {

    $('#inputTitle').val($('.highcharts-title tspan').html());
    $('.highcharts-title tspan').html("");
    $('#inputTitle').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#inputTitle').focus();
});

$('.highcharts-title').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

The keyup function is for defining the **`enter key`** for the input submission. The second line in the **`enterkey bind`** is for the export problem. Without changing the title in the chart options, it doesn't show in the export. Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hocw9vym/1/).

Comment: Instead of setting options inline, call [`chart.setTitle({ text: new_title })`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle).

Comment: You can use `useHTML` title option and wrap your title into any html tag with id provided to make your life easier.  `title: {text: '<strong id="graph-title">My old title</strong>', useHTML: true}`